# PHP's json_decode fails to decode valid JSON

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, json

So I have this JSON object:

```
[
    {
        "branch_id": "1",
        "issue_id": "1",
        "user_id": "5",
        "parent_id": null,
        "level": "1",
        "name": "troll",
        "description": "yup",
        "add_date": "2012-10-24 20:26:04",
        "children": [
            {
                "branch_id": "2",
                "issue_id": "1",
                "user_id": "5",
                "parent_id": "1",
                "level": "2",
                "name": "sdad",
                "description": "dssfsd",
                "add_date": "2012-10-24 20:52:52",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "branch_id": "4",
                        "issue_id": "1",
                        "user_id": "5",
                        "parent_id": "2",
                        "level": "3",
                        "name": "fdgffd",
                        "description": "ghjjhjghjj",
                        "add_date": "2012-10-25 17:51:53",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "branch_id": "3",
        "issue_id": "1",
        "user_id": "5",
        "parent_id": null,
        "level": "1",
        "name": "dgdfg",
        "description": "dfgfgdfg",
        "add_date": "2012-10-24 20:52:52",
        "children": []
    }
  ]
```

For some reason, when I try to decode it with PHP's json_decode, it doesn't output anything. The object can't be invalid, because both JSONLint and this [parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) parse it correctly and throw no errors. PHP's own json_last_error method doesn't throw any errors either.

I think the non-existent output might have something to do with the object having multidimensional arrays, but I'm not sure. What do you think?

**EDIT**

A little background here:

This JSON object is retrieved from [this file](http://skibb.it/api/issues/branches?issue_id=1). It's from an (in development) API, and this particular resource returns a JSON object from a certain "branch collection". 
I fetch this JSON object to PHP with cUrl, here's the code for that:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://skibb.it/api/issues/branches?issue_id=1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$branches = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

That should be also error free, because it gets the plain JSON object correctly. But when I try:

```
$branches = json_decode($branches);
var_dump($branches); //Or print_r($branches);
```

It just doesn't output anything, except NULL.

**FINAL EDIT**

Yup, this is embarassing. Found out after looking through the code, that I had accidentaly left a print_r() in the encoding process during debugging phase, which outputted the JSON object and a **number 1 after it**. But thanks for the replies, they were helpfull in distinguishing the problem's source!

Comment: I would try removing the children element from the objects in the array and verify that you receive output.

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.org/7nfvsQS0

Comment: How are you getting this JSON string?

Comment: "So I have this JSON object". You are supposed to deal with a string to decode it. Show us your code.

Comment: That's insane. We both used the same HEREDOC delimiter. Ha. Little coincidental I think. http://codepad.org/LyRSQNPG

Comment: You're probably just trying to use it wrong.  `$obj = json_decode($yourstring);  echo $obj[0]->branch_id;  // would display 1`

Comment: @Layke: I always use delimiters that say what the text is.  Such as `XML`, `HTML` or `JSON` :-P

Comment: There is a stray `1` in the JSON, after the last closing `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your JSON. As you say, it parses correctly. Just so you are aware, when you "decode", nothing gets outputted. You still have to do something with it. Don't expect to see a dump after the decode.

See here:

http://codepad.org/LyRSQNPG

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample json decoding.

```
$jsonDayArray    = $_REQUEST['jsonDayArray'];
    $jsonDayArray    = str_replace("\\","",$jsonDayArray);
    $DayArray = array();
    $DayArray = json_decode($jsonDayArray, true);
```